# how to make global variable and functions which can be accessible in all the components in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, global

I am struggling with **global variables** as I want some variables which I need to access in all the components so what should i do in **angular 4**.

*I've tried something like this:*

Created one file with the name of `global.ts` and made a class with the name `GlobalComponent` something like this

```
export class GlobalComponent {
  globalVar:string = "My Global Value";
}
```

and am using it on HeaderComponent by importing and making instance and it's working fine but this is very long process to import in each and every files to get it available.

**So I want it to be available on all the components without importing it.**

Is there any way or trick to achieve this? Any suggestion would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

As @bgraham is suggesting, it is definitely better to let angular injector to instantiate the service.

But you could also export just a simple object with key-value pairs, including functions. Then you can simply import it and use it (without the instantiation part).

globals.ts file:

```
export const GLOBALS = {
  globalVar: 'My Global Value',
  globalFunc: () => alert('123')
};
```

your.component.ts file:

```
import { GLOBALS } from './globals.ts';

console.log(GLOBALS.globalVar);
GLOBALS.globalFunc();
```

Btw I don't think there is a way how to get rid of the import statement - that is part of how typescript works...

Comment: Yes @martin -  You're very right, But it's also tough task to import same file in 800 components

Comment: Yeah I understand, but as I also noted in my answer, there is probably no way to get rid of the import statement as it is needed by typescript to know what you are trying to access...

Comment: this does not permit you to call it in the html which is what I want.

Comment: To access GLOBALS in component template, you will need to define it as a class member of that component.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want to do is possible and it's probably not a good idea.

The import statements are how webpack (or other bundlers) are able to build a tree to figure out which files to include. So it might be tricky to get global files built into all your bundles.

Also I would add, I'm not sure just importing the static file is the way to go either. It's kind of quick and dirty, which maybe is what you want I guess, but for production apps I would recommend making an angular service and injecting it.

```
export class GlobalVariablesService {
  globalVar:string = "My Global Value";
}
```

This way you can mock these for unit tests or potentially pass in different variables depending on your changing needs in the future.

If you need these to update and push that into lots of components throughout your app, you might look into Redux. Its pretty handy for that kind of thing.

Sorry, perhaps not the answer you were hoping for

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion, It's just my point of view for the largest app which has more then 1000 components and we need to add global file in around 800 components. so it will be so lengthy and bad way to get it done and very tough to manage after year. Isn't it?

Comment: It will be a little lengthy for sure. It's also annoying to have to import { Component } from @angular all the time, but that is part of the architecture which makes sure code is bundled efficiently. Its a trade off. On the other hand, I don't think it will be touch to manage. There's no global namespace pollution which is a plus. And you will have fine grained control over your Service. It will be easy to change and update in the future when its in 800 places. The Service is just in one place, but imported everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create constant file - constant.ts under src folder.

Now import constant.ts file whenever you require parameter to be called

It will look like so

export const constant = {
  COSNT_STRING : 'My Global Value',
}

how to use constant:

1) Import file.
2) constant.CONST_STRING

Also this is a good practice from future prospective, if you want to modify response just made change in one file not in 800 files.

Comment: and about changes in files, we still need to do changes in 800 files to just importing constant file